Hide the main page content view
I am not using the main content view for the front page. It is showing the message that I still don't have any content assigned to the main page.
How do I disable this message?

Follow the official documentation Designating a Front Page for your Site.

Site prerequisites
The content item that you want to designate as the front page of your
site must exist.
Steps
In the Manage administrative menu, navigate to Configuration > System > Basic site settings (admin/config/system/site-information). Under Front page, replace /node with the name of the page you would like to
make the home page. To use the home page that was previously created,
provide its path /home. Click Save configuration.

